# What is the disadvantage of handling pppoe by the modem instead of the routeur?

Tags: networking, router

My new ISP forces to use its modem to dial PPPoE whereas I used to use my customized router for that task. When I called their customer service, they suggest me that I set my router to get a private address on its WAN side.

I wonder if that would leave most of my router's function useless, such as QoS, firewall, port forwarding etc.

Comment: To clarify, the modem ISP provided can both serve as a modem and a basic router (with wifi setups). The reason I want to add my own router is that I want to have more control than just what the ISP modem (with basic router function) provides. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, they've provided a "home gateway" not just a modem.

Right now you have Double NAT. Thats not ideal. If it were bridged it would be perfect but the ISP won't allow this and also wont provide you the credentials. It sounds like the ISP's policy is the issue here.

As its a policy issue your options are:

- Try and extract the credentials from their gateway (not easy usually)
- Change ISP
- Accept that you must use their equipment and configure your own router as an access point (DHCP off, Static LAN IP, NOT using WAN port)

Answer (score 0):

The only disadvantage of using a modem and a router is you'd have to power two devices, not one.

If your router has a WAN port, then you can use your modem only to connect to the internet. Just connect them both by putting an Ethernet cable in LAN port of the modem and in WAN port of the router.

All functions of your router should still work.

Answer (score 0):

No, your router will still function exactly the same but without the modem device.

Consumer routers are actually a collection of many different devices and services, one of which, in your case, is a modem.

This is under the assumption that the device they are telling you to use *is* just a modem and not it's own router as well. If it is, you may end up with any number of issues by running both, so make sure the device is definitely just a modem.

Comment: The modem they provide also works as router.

Comment: @Alex Do you know the make and model? Ideally you'd be able to put it into `bridge mode` and remove all the router functionality.

Comment: You are absolutely right. However, the ISP refused to put it into "bridge mode" and its option is greyed out on my side (they seem to have a superuser account for it). And...I am now in China. Brand, huawei ofc....

Comment: That's why I am asking the drawback of not using router to dial, instead of how to break their restriction...